# Android App Crashes, Implementing SlidingMenu

Tags: java, android

I created an empty project to try to implement the SlidingMenu from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu:

When I run my application, it crashes on start and I don't know what went wrong.

My Android code:

```
public class _iSellCrazyStuff extends SlidingActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__i_sell_crazy_stuff);

        setTitle(R.string.attach);
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
    }
}
```

My logcat:

```
06-26 01:10:40.340: E/Trace(28664): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-26 01:10:40.364: W/dalvikvm(28664): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/it3783application/_iSellCrazyStuff; (473)
06-26 01:10:40.364: W/dalvikvm(28664): Link of class 'Lcom/example/it3783application/_iSellCrazyStuff;' failed
06-26 01:10:40.364: D/AndroidRuntime(28664): Shutting down VM
06-26 01:10:40.364: W/dalvikvm(28664): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4129c930)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.it3783application/com.example.it3783application._iSellCrazyStuff}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.it3783application._iSellCrazyStuff" on path: /data/app/com.example.it3783application-1.apk
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.it3783application._iSellCrazyStuff" on path: /data/app/com.example.it3783application-1.apk
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2220)
06-26 01:10:40.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28664):    ... 11 more
06-26 01:10:40.372: I/Process(28664): Sending signal. PID: 28664 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you have import ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: are you using sliding menu and sherlock at once? if yes, so to main project add dependency sliding menu, and to sliding menu add dependency action bar. Also sliding classes should extends xxxSherlockActivity.. you will have change them also in sliding menu library. Then your project will work

Comment: There's a NPE being thrown by the SlidingMenu class.  Maybe you need to set the menu before you call `attachToActivity` ?

Comment: @deadfish, I did the following, here is the updated errors

Comment: I would like to invite you to chat, maybe we will figure it out http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32438/android-app-crashes-implementing-slidingmenu-updated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not have imported the ActionBarSherlock library correctly. If using Eclipse, make sure you File -> Import -> Import from Existing Code and select the library. 
Then under your project, go to properties and java-build-path -> projects -> add dependencies

Comment: i tried to did what you said, I deleted everything and fresh install them, adding dependencies. It still crashes